# ionic 4 - Set background image for full page

Tags: css, ionic-framework, background-image, footer, ionic4

I am trying to set background image for full page with `footer` content

```
<ion-content class='background' fullscreen>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer no-border>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col><ion-button size="large" fill='outline' expand="block" color="primary" (click)="goSearch()">English</ion-button></ion-col>
        <ion-col><ion-button size="large" fill='outline' expand="block" color="secondary" (click)="goSearch()">العربية</ion-button></ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-footer>
```

Above code is not setting the background image to full page and displays the page as,

[image]

I tried to set ion-row transparent and it is not working as expected.

```
ion-row {
  --background: transparent;
  --ion-color-base: transparent !important;
}
```

But if I remove  or  in the footer, it works as expected.

```
<ion-footer no-border>
    <ion-button size="large" fill='outline' expand="block" color="primary" (click)="goSearch()">English</ion-button>
    <ion-button size="large" fill='outline' expand="block" color="secondary" (click)="goSearch()">العربية</ion-button>
</ion-footer>
```

[image]

As need to add some more controls, is there any way to make elements in the footer transparent?

Version:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.1.0",
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
.background {
  --background: url("/assets/icon/background.jpg") 0 0/100% 100% no-repeat
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-header translucent="true" no-border>
    <ion-toolbar>
       <ion-buttons color="secondary" slot="start">
          <ion-back-button color="secondary" text="" icon="arrow-round-back"></ion-back-button>
       </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title></ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
```

```
<ion-content fullscreen="true" class="background">
   <!-- Content here  -->
</ion-content>
```